# Hello World PHP example for storing & reading a file in free Google Cloud Storage bucket from Google Apps Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-php

I couldn't find out there a **PHP tutorial** for **storing** a file in the *free* bucket of a Google Apps Engine project and **retrieving** its contents. The idea of this post is to do it step by step assuming the GAE project was correctly created.

1) If you created a GAE project it has been granted a 5Gb of a free Google Cloud Storage bucket. Its name is "**YOUR_PROJECT_ID**.appspot.com"

https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser

2) A *Service Account* must be created and asgigned to use the SDK.

> Steps Here

3) This is the basic PHP code to store a file with a "Hello World" content. This code could be executed from the terminal windows.

```
<?php    

$filename = "tutorial.txt"; // filename in the bucket
$txt_toSave = "Hello Word"; // text content in the file  

// lets add code here

?>
```

> php GCStorage_save_example.php

4) This is the basic PHP code to retrieve a file's content from the bucket.

```
<?php    
// lets add code here

echo $txt_fileContent;
?>
```

> php GCStorage_retrieve_example.php

a) if permissions must be granted feel free to add the step
b) if any other step must be done feel free to add it

Answer (score 0):

You can find the PHP code samples for Google Cloud Storage operations in the Official Google Cloud Storage documentation [1].

For instance, an example to store a file in Google Cloud Storage according to the documentation [2] would be:

```php
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

/**
 * Upload a file.
 *
 * @param string $bucketName the name of your Google Cloud bucket.
 * @param string $objectName the name of the object.
 * @param string $source the path to the file to upload.
 *
 * @return Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface
 */
function upload_object($bucketName, $objectName, $source)
{
    $storage = new StorageClient();
    $file = fopen($source, 'r');
    $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
    $object = $bucket->upload($file, [
        'name' => $objectName
    ]);
    printf('Uploaded %s to gs://%s/%s' . PHP_EOL, basename($source), $bucketName, $objectName);
}
```

You can follow the How-To [3] for retrieving an object from the bucket as well. Note that this is no different than storing/downloading objects from other buckets, as you can specify from which bucket to pull/push from.

- [1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/how-to
- [2] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects
- [3] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects